# Когда использовать JDBC, а когда — Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, jdbc, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

Учитель мне задал вопрос, на который я не смог ответить. Когда использовать JDBC,  а когда — Spring Data JPA?

Answer (score 2):

Когда нужно делать сложные запросы к БД и не используется Spring Data JPA, то тогда надо использовать JDBC. В противном случае, если нет необходимости составлять сложные запросы, и используется Spring Data JPA, даже если и надо составлять такие запросы в Spring Data JPA, то использовать нативные запросы. JDBC представляет собой API для низкоуровневого доступа к БД, и по возможности следует избегать такого доступа, поскольку низкоуровневое программирование всегда сложнее, чем высокоуровневое, такое как Spring Data JPA.

Для более детального ознакомления и сравнения различий советую прочитать эту статью:

## [JDBC vs JPA](https://habr.com/ru/companies/otus/articles/686082/):

> **JDBC**. Абсолютно все библиотеки, взаимодействующие с базами данных, используют JDBC. В этом есть как преимущества, так и недостатки. По сути, JDBC — это Java-реализация стандартного подхода к работе с базами данных, реализованного во всех подобных технологиях:
>
> - Открыть соединение.
> - Открыть курсор.
> - Отправить запрос.
> - Обработать набор данных.
> - Закрыть результирующий набор / курсор.
> - Закрыть соединение.
>
> И вы наверняка сталкивались с ситуацией, когда, выполняя десятки запросов, забывали закрыть соединение. А шесть недель спустя получали ужасный стек-трейс из-за того, что каким-то образом в базе данных закончились соединения или курсоры.
>
> Вы быстро понимали в чем дело, чинили и отправляли в релиз. Но через восемь недель — та же самая ошибка.
>
> **Spring Data JPA** помогает вам с простыми запросами и избавляет от необходимости работать с `EntityManager` из JPA.
>
> Хотя рано или поздно вам все-равно придется писать JPQL-запросы вручную.
>
> Но если вы думаете, что написав, сложный и тонко настроенный JPQL-запрос вы сможете каким-то образом настроить генерацию оптимального SQL-запроса, вас ждет большое разочарование.

Comment: Если ответ помог решить проблему, то ему надо поставить галочку и голосовать за. Чекбоксы находятся слева от ответа.